# DownloadManager download "stopping" during the download

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I am attempting a download through the DownloadManager.  It is calling just fine and seems to initialize just fine.  I can see a file is created in my "music" directory and it even starts to grow a bit.  Once it gets to around 3-4 MB then the download will cancel and say "download" unsuccessful.  This might be because I am downloading from a slow source but it is definitely available.  Any ideas on how to not have this quit/timeout.  Below is the function that i am using.

In case it is important.  I am calling this from an Asynchronous method and I am looping thorough a map that will begin the download of 20 (or so) mp3 files.

Thanks,
Craig

```
 private void download(String strUrl, String fileName){
    try {

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(strUrl));
        request.setDescription(strUrl);
        request.setTitle(fileName);request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC,fileName);

        // get download service and enqueue file
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("ERROR: ", e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - I never found a good answer to this question but once I fixed my network it seemed to go away.  It still occassionally happens but it is relatively infrequent and appears to be network related.

Comment: Were you downloading form a secure site or password-protected directory? If so, it might be related to this (6-year-old!) bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1353